# Decomposing the top of a module

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

Let $M$ be a finitely generated Artinian $R$-module. Then there exists a decomposition $M = \oplus_{i=1}^kM_i$ such that each $M_i$ is an indecomposable submodule of $M$. It is known that $\text{rad}(M) = \oplus_{i=1}^k\text{rad}(M_i)$ and $\text{soc}(M) = \oplus_{i=1}^k\text{soc}(M_i)$.

I'm able to prove that $\text{top}(M) = \oplus_{i=1}^k\text{top}(M_i)$, where $\text{top}(M) := M/\text{rad}(M)$, however I'm wondering if this result has been established in the literature? This is for my MSc thesis, and I would rather not include a proof of a result that is well-known.

Thanks.

Comment: You have a soc that should be rad. That equality is well known. See, for example, the book by Anderson and Fuller on modules.

Comment: Btw, all these equalities actually hold for arbitrary direct sums.

Comment: Fixed. Would you mind referring me to the result in this text? I've scoured it a few times, and haven't come across it before. Thanks.

Comment: In the book *Rings and categories of modules* by Anderson and Fuller you will find a detailed treatment of the radical, and in particular the proof that the radical of an arbitrary direct sum is the direct sum of the radicals. The statement about the tops follows at once from that.

Comment: This is Proposition 8.18 in the book. The radical is the reject for the class of simple modules — this is explained around proposition 9.13.

Comment: Thanks a bunch.

Comment: You should write an answer with all your findings, for reference!

Comment: I ended up realising the present statement as being a consequence of a certain dual equivalence of categories, so I didn't actually take the time to understand the notion of a 'reject'. I will return to this post in a couple of weeks, and provide such an answer.

Comment: That sounds like an overcomplication... This is a *really* elementary fact.